# Create a foreign table identifier with FactoryGirl - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

I have two models, User and Answer. I would like to generate a user_id in the FactoryGirl creation of Answer. How would I go about this?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    pasword { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  end
end
```

And the following is what I have so far for generating a foreign user_id (obviously incorrect syntax):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :answer do
    description { Faker::Lorem.words }
    user_id = FactoryGirl.create(:user)::user_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the association `answer belongs_to: :user`, you can use `association` helper in factory definition as:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :answer do
    description { Faker::Lorem.words }
    association :user
  end
end
```

Then the usage:

```
u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
answer = FactoryGirl.create(:answer, user: u)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :answer do
    description { Faker::Lorem.words }

    after(:build) do |answer, evaluator|
      answer.user = create(:user) unless answer.user
    end
  end
end
```

This will create a new user if a user isn't provided when creating the answer.